# Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables with the same mean $µ = 1/2$. Let ($Z,W) := (X,X +Y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent exponential random variables with the same mean
$µ = 1/2$. Let ($Z,W) := (X,X +Y)$

i) Find the regions where the joint pdf of $(Z,W)$ is positive.
ii) Find the joint pdf of $(Z,W)$.

I know how to find the joint pdf, but how does one find where it is positive? And I'm not sure how I am supposed to find where it is positive before I actually find the joint pdf.

Comment: Well, for (i): can the pdf be positive at any point $(a,b)$ where $0 < b < a$?

Answer (score 1):

Since Y is a positive random variable, only outcomes with w=x+y>x=z are possible.

Because all positive values are possibilities for Y and X, the pdf will be posive for all z=x>0 and all w=x+y>x=z.

It follows that pdf is positive at {(z, w): z>0, w>z}.

No need to compute the pdf to determine where pdf is positive in above reasoning.

In fact, the above reasoning for the random vector (Z,W) as defined as long as X and Y only assume non-negative values though the pdf itself will be different according to the particular case.